# how to change errors in Django rest framework like PK to ID

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
{
"status": 400,
"errors": [
"designation Invalid pk "2" - object does not exist.",
"provincedetails Invalid pk "10" - object does not exist."
]
}
```

I know why this errors is throwing because relation object is not exist so..
But I want to customize this error like to remove PK and add ID, is that possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a custom `Exception` handler, as described in the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling)
There you can search for `pk` (mind the spaces!) and replace it  with `id`. Beware that this is hacky. If doing it via localization is easier, I would definitly use that option instead. That being said, I don't know why you would want to change form `pk` to `id` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Did not try to do that, but looks like error text holds inside

```
django-rest-framework/rest_framework/locale/{LANG_CODE}/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
```

So you can change error message using custom [internationalization](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/internationalization/)